# numel(isnan(A)) == numel(~isnan(A)) == numel(A)?

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a 121x601 [matrix](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pwmi3g9bkmimuau/zeta.mat?dl=0) with some `NaN` values.

I cannot understand the reason of the following inconsistency:

```
>> size(A,1)*size(A,2)

ans =

       72721

>> numel(~isnan(A))

ans =

       72721

>> numel(isnan(A))

ans =

       72721
```

Can anybody point it to me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numel` returns the number of elements of the matrix, independently of what they are. `isnan(A)` transforms each element in `A` to a boolean, depending if the corresponding element is NaN or not. But both matrices `isnan(A)` and its complement `~isnan(A)` have the same number of elements, namely, the number of elements of the original matrix, `A`.

See more about [`numel`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) and [`isnan`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html).

Comment: so `numel(A(~isnan(A)))` is what I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @shamalaia Or simply `sum(~isnan(A))`.

Comment: @shamalaia Just to mix it up, `nnz(~isnan(A))` would also work.

Comment: @Holt, no no no! `sum(~isnan(A))` will return a column vector with the number of non-NaN elements in each column. `sum(A)` calculates the sum of each column by default. The right way to do this is either `sum(sum(~isnan(A)));`, `sum(~isnan(A(:)))`;` or as craigim suggests `nnz(~isnan(A))`. I think the last one is the best one...

Comment: Ah right. I'm used to NumPy, there's not need for that kind of trickery there.

Comment: I would say `nnz` is the best option, since `sum(sum(~isnan(A)));` works only for 2D matrices which might be ok for that specific problem but is not a general solution. `sum(~isnan(A(:)))` will also work but you are adding boolean values, which Matlab accepts but it is "conceptually" wrong.